# Выбрать одно значение из всех найденных значений SQL

Tags: php, sql

Есть база данных, в ней находится 10 строк в постоянном обновлении (удаление и запись). После выборки `SELECT * FROM general WHERE posting = false`, остается ещё минимум 7-8 записей. Можно ли из получившегося результат брать (например) только первую строку. Или как лучше сделать выборку по 1 ед из базы данных?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM general WHERE posting = false limit 1`. стоит указать `order` если нужна повторяемость результата

Comment: И тут я почувствовал себя дураком =\ Спасибо за помощь